# @react-native-firebase_app' could not be found in project

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

In my React Native 0.68.2 "expo": "^45.0.0" app i'm trying to use react-native-firebase and i have done everything except react-native-link as it's not supported in the latest version of React Native. When I run my project, it shows error from the node module of react-native-firebase. I'm guessing it's happening for some version conflict. Here is the long error :

> Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on
> your Android project by calling firebase.app().
>
> Ensure you have:
>
> imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage'
> module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.
>
> Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN
> 'getPackages()' method list.
>
> See http://invertase.link/android for full setup instructions.

Here's my app build/gradle file dependencies:

```
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4')
classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
classpath('de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2')
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
```

And my android/app/build/gradle :

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
implementation project(path: ":@react-native-firebase_messaging")
implementation project(path: ":@react-native-firebase_app")
```

And setting.gradle :

```
include ':@react-native-firebase_messaging'
project(':@react-native-firebase_messaging').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, './../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/android')

include ':@react-native-firebase_app'
project(':@react-native-firebase_app').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, './../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/android')
```

And MainApplication :

```
import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingPackage;
packages.add(new ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingPackage());
```

App.js :

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log("Message handled in the background!", remoteMessage);
})

const unsub = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage=>{
  Alert.alert('A new FCM msg arrived', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage))
  console.log(remoteMessage);
  return unsub;
})
```

app.json :

```
"plugins": [
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
      "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics",
      
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
```

Comment: Have you added google services ? 
Check this link https://rnfirebase.io/#configure-firebase-with-android-credentials

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelShoukat Yeah I did I followed this website step by step but still doesn't work